# Replacing a string when I only know the first few characters

Tags: regex, string, replace, str-replace

I'm trying to write a batch file that will search my text file for a string and replace it. The string will be some numbers that will never change followed by 8 numbers that represent a date. I want to be able to replace that date with the current date, but I wont know what the date in the string is currently set to, so I can only search for the string by searching for those first 4 unchanging characters.

For example my text file could have a line in it that says 123419072015 (1234) that I want to replace with 123420072015

How do I replace 8 characters without knowing what they are, by searching for the preceding 4 characters of that string?

I tried to figure something out by searching around and came up with this, only to realise how flawed this method was for what I'm trying to do. Needless to say I don't really know what I'm doing.
This replaces every line with today's date, leaving the first 4 characters.

```
set Today=%date:~10,4%%date:~7,2%%date:~4,2%

@echo off

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

set INTEXTFILE=test_in.txt

set OUTTEXTFILE=test_out.txt

set SEARCHTEXT=1234

set REPLACETEXT=%Today%

SET _startchar=0

SET _length=4

set OUTPUTLINE=

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=¶" %%A in ( '"type %INTEXTFILE%"') do (
SET string=%%A
CALL SET modified=%%string:~%_startchar%,%_length%%%

echo !modified!%Today% >> %OUTTEXTFILE%
)
del %INTEXTFILE%
rename %OUTTEXTFILE% %INTEXTFILE%
```

Surely there's an easy solution to this?
I'm really struggling to find anything just by searching.
Any help would be great!

Comment: `\b1234\d{8}\b` replace with `1234` + cur_date

Comment: Are you stuck using Windows .BAT/CMD files?

Comment: Also, in your example, you show some parentheses that end up delimiting data to be deleted.  Is this always true?

Comment: I wanted to use a .BAT so that I could add it as a scheduled task to run every morning.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the easiest solution would be to get `sed` from the [GnuWin32](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages.html) toolkit and use it, something like

```
sed "s/\b1234[0-9]\{4\}\([0-9]\{4\}\)\b/12342007\1/g" <%INPUTTEXTFILE% >%OUTPUTTEXTFILE%
```

That's based on the information you've given, finding the fixed string `1234` followed by eight digits, then changing the first four of those digits to `2007`. Obviously, if your requirements are a little more complex, the `sed` command may need to be adjusted.

But it'll be easier doing that than trying to do it in the `cmd` language which, though it's come a long way, is still not up to the level of similar UNIX tools.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want a pattern like "1234[0-9]{8}" or "1234\d{8}" and if you want to capture the unique portion then "1234(\d{8})"

Then you would replace with %date%$1 where the $1 is the match from the ()